# Is there an updates checker extension for commercial extensions?

Tags: development, third-party-module, package

I was wondering if there are any extension stores which allow small developers to sign up (like [nr-apps.com](http://www.nr-apps.com/store/list-your-magento-extensions.html) does) and publish their own work, but also have a ready made version checker which contacts the store?

Obviously the Connect Manager does this for free extensions but it's useless otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

So far the closest I've encountered is [Xtension Galaxy](https://xtensiongalaxy.com/).  It claims:

- Code repository for automatic software updates to Xtension Galaxy
- Initially our plan is to let customers download 90 days of updates (in keeping with common industry practice).